# Finding repeated strings in a list

Tags: c++

I have a list:

```
Class Name Surname
Math John Johnson
Programming Tom Tomson
Physics John Johnson
```

I'd like to find out which teacher teaches the most classes and return it as a string. I have written a simple class to save, take, add information.

```
template <typename tip>
string FindTeacher(List <tip> & A)
{
string module, surname, name, TeacherX;
for (int i = 0; i < A.Length(); i++)
{
tip kk = A.Take(i);
kk.Take(module, surname, name);
//stuck on this part, what to do next?
//how do i find that John Johnson teaches 2 classes, and Tom teaches only 1
}
return TeacherX;
}
```

I am terribly sorry if it's hard to understand me, english is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::unodered_map`, or `std::map`
with `std::pair<std::string, std::string> >` as key,
and size_t as data, and every time you get:
`kk.Take(module, surname, name);`
find by key(surname,name), if no insert with 1 as data, else increase data by one.